# Command line in a Python script

Tags: python

I'm using `subprocess` to call command line. For example,

```
subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
```

This is for one argument. I want to call an executable called "myFuntion" and pass *several* arguments to it, by their names. The command line I would have written is:

```
./myFunction --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2
```

How do I "translate" this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: each argument is a separate element in the list.

So, if you understand how the shell would separate out this command line:

```
./myFunction --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2
```

… you know what the arguments are. When there are no quotes or escapes or anything else fancy, the shell just separates on spaces. So this is just 5 arguments:

```
subprocess.check_output(["./myFunction", "--arg1", "a1", "--arg2", "a2"])
```

If you have a command line that you're not sure how to translate, you can ask your shell to do it for you… or just use the [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) module in Python:

```
>>> print(shlex.split('./myFunction --arg1 a1 --arg2 a2'))
['./myFunction', '--arg1', 'a1', '--arg2', 'a2']
```